# Locally hosted HTTPS site gives Chrome error about a websocket (when using ParcelJS bundles)

Tags: google-chrome, iis, websocket, parceljs

I am not using Web Sockets on this web page , but -

I am trying to understand why Chrome console prints the following "error" (I use quotes because it does not effect anything). The error only appears when I host on a HTTPS site, not HTTP (the same IIS server which is local to my computer is being used).

(and there is a valid TLS/SSL certificate)m, I have no idea why port 61396 is being looked at..

```
hmr-runtime.js:29 WebSocket connection to 'wss://ysg4206.draper.com:61396/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
parcelRequire.../../../node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/builtins/hmr-runtime.js @ hmr-runtime.js:29
```

Comment: which type of certificate you are using self-signed or valid CA? which port you are assigned to `wss://` and `https://`? try to use `wss://ysg4206.draper.com` or `ws://ysg4206.draper.com` not `wss://ysg4206.draper.com:61396/`.

Comment: CA signed. The port was picked by the parcel bundler for hot load modules. I turned that off, and the errors stopped.

Comment: is your issue is resolved?

Comment: Could you share your iis site binding and with which port number you bind the certificate in web socket?

Comment: Yea it is resolved

Comment: You did not solve the problem. The parceljs folks did.

Comment: You could post your solution and mark as answer.

Comment: Later today I hope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/3286

but the gist of the solution is that HMR is for development hot module reloading. If you have a different way of doing live reloads (like the VSCODE live server) then you should

> This is part of the hot module reloading feature. You can disable it
>   via --no-hmr. Otherwise, you'll have to proxy the websocket through
>   your IIS proxy as well (if I understood your setup correctly).

Answer (score 4):

From https://parceljs.org/hmr.html

> Hot Module Replacement (HMR) improves the development experience by
> automatically updating modules in the browser at runtime without
> needing a whole page refresh. This means that application state can be
> retained as you change small things. Parcel's HMR implementation
> supports both JavaScript and CSS assets.

and for that it uses **WebSockets**.

You can do three things:

1. To make it go away just disable hmr: `parcel entry.js --no-hmr`
2. To use HMR you can run your solution as **non-https** site or ...
3. You can generate self-signed certificate and use it with IIS as well as parcel:

   `parcel entry.js --cert certificate.cert --key private.key`

It's all here: https://parceljs.org/cli.html